# Remove a keyboard shortcut from VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I was able to overwrite any keyboard shortcut from VS Code just by adding a new key in the `keybindings.json` file.

However I can't remove an existing shortcut. More specifically, I'd like to remove this one:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+down",         
  "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
  "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

Any ideas on how I can remove it?

Comment: Found a Issue
[^] when holding Ctrl in order for enabling clicking on methods(and such)
by moving the cursor around and even on the spot,
code regions are closed;

Microsoft Visual Studio Code 1.53.2

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is [covered in our documentation for keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_removing-a-specific-key-binding-rule). Just add a `-` before the command name.

For your example, try adding:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+down", "command": "-editor.action.insertCursorBelow" }
```

to your `keybindings.json`

Comment: this was seemingly not working for me. had to restart vscode before my new mapping took effect

Comment: Removing doesn't seem supported at the moment if you're creating a keyboard shortcut extension. VSCode seems to add an extra '-' and assumes it's an odd command...

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Vscode is awesome but keybindings are one of its weakest features. If I want to unbind a default keyboard shortcut, like the hideous command-shift-c, I have to know what command it runs, even though it's not going to get run, and put a minus in front of it? Why does it take a command at all? Couldn't any command be put there? How do we make this better?

Comment: @AndyRay There are some GUI driven solutions listed in other answers, involving some trial and error, but try this. command palette -> "Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting" Helps in a lot of cases.

Comment: Hmm, I just added `{ "key": "alt+z" }` (without `"command"` key) to `keybindings.json` and it removed the shortcut.

Answer (score 42):

1. Goto Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. The above should open what screenshot shows (list of all keyboard bindings)
3. Right click on the keyboard binding you like to delete
4. Select Remove Keybinding

This should delete the Keybinding.

[image: Remove Keybinding from vscode]

In fact, under the hood this also edits your `keybindings.json`. 
To see the effect, after opening Keyboard Shortcuts, click on the icon having the mouseover text `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`:

[image: Open keybindings.json]

If you need more help, try:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: I think your answer is more generic (more helpful for _similar_ questions), and therefore preferable to the answer by Matt Bierner.

Answer (score 10):

Overwriting it with an empty command seems to do the trick:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+down", "command": "",
                          "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

Comment: The empty command worked for me removing "shift+alt+u" while adding "-" had no detectable effect. Thank you Felix.

Comment: This also worked to remove chords, such as ctrl+r in the terminal conflicting with the npm extension!

Answer (score 8):

- `File` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` -***or***-
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
  (`Code` > `Preferences` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` -***or***-
  <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> on macOS).
- Right-click on the key-binding you want to delete
  (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `DownArrow` in this case).
- Click `Remove Keybinding`.

[image: Remove Keybinding]

This edits your `keybindings.json`.
To see it, click on the icon in the top right corner that looks as
below (tooltip = `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`) :

[image: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)]

If you need more help, try:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: This answer needs a rewrite to make it more helpful/useful.
(And this comment is just a kind reminder to myself that I should rewrite it whenever I get the time to do so, which unfortunately is NOT NOW.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're wondering how to open this file for editing in newer versions:

1. File > Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.
2. Click the `{}` icon in the top right of the editor.

[image]

3. Then follow the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Simpler way with the UI:

1. Open the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab ([see @Nelu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55983746))
2. Select the command you want to remove from shortcuts
3. Press the <kbd>del</kbd> keyboard

And voilà! :-)

Comment: Pressing delete doesn't work for me, I had to right click and press "Remove Keybinding". Running VSCode 1.41.1

Comment: Pressing Delete does nothing for me either.  And neither does right-clicking and selecting  "Remove keybinding".  It *does* seem to change it in the keybinding.json file though.  (Visual Studio Code 1.43.0, April 2020)

Answer (score -1):

Go to **File** > **Preferences** > **Keyboard shortcuts**

If you added a user shortcut type then look for Source: User. The right click **Remove**

[image]