# What is the shortcut for displaying the GitGraph tab on VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

[GitGraph for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) is an awesome tool for a Git users. You can see the git log along the timeline and easily checkout to different branches by double clicking the branch icon. Creating a new branch at a specific commit and reverting a certain branch to any commit can't be easier with this extension.

To open the GitGraph tab, you should mouse-click the corresponding item on status bar.

[image]

But is there a shortcut for opening this tab using only keyboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you go to the Git Graph contributions tabs, you see that there is none:

[image: GitGrap contributions]

But you could configure VS Code keyboard shorcuts to add one...

[image: Configure shortcuts]

Comment: i get ' gitgraph view not found' when executing the configured command, plus no gitgraph icon appears on the status bar. although i got it installed ...

Comment: For everyone else, checkout this post if you have a collision between your preferred shortcut and success. It'll show you how to remove the existing shortcut, so that you can add the new one if that's what you wish:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184034/remove-a-keyboard-shortcut-from-vs-code