# Is there a way to disable shift + enter in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I keep pressing shift + enter in VSCode by accident and it brings up the terminal, is there a way to disable this shortcut?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a keyboard shortcut from VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184034/remove-a-keyboard-shortcut-from-vs-code)

Answer (score 7):

Open the shortcuts settings on vscode (either from "settings", or with "Ctrl + K, Ctrl + S") and search which shortcut you have assigned to "Shift Enter".

You can enter "Shift Enter" directly in the search box to see those.

Then edit or delete those you don't want

Comment: Thanks, this is specially frustrating when using VIM keybindings in python files

Comment: Thank you, Ctrl + K, Ctrl+S works well.

Answer (score -2):

On Visual Studio 2019 with default settings, go to:

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard.

Under "Show commmands containing:", type: **Edit.SmartBreakLine**

Then click Remove [Shortcut].

--

THEN, do same for "InteractiveConsole.BreakLine", and again remove the Shift+Enter shortcut.

Side effect on InteractiveConsole.BreakLine: After removing the shortcut, If you keep holding shift + enter to type a normal new line after removing InteractiveConsole.BreakLine, (without getting auto-complete-stuff), you won't get a new line.

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio Code.